# Card.js:53 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'image') at MediaCard

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, axios

I'm working on a live auctions app using the MERN stack (MongoDB, Express, React, Node.js), and I've run into an issue that's causing me some trouble. When I load a component called MediaCard in my React front-end, I'm getting the following error:

```js
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'image')
    at MediaCard (Card.js:53:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
```

also that's my MediaCard function in ReactJs

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import Card from "@mui/material/Card";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
// Actions
import {
  loadAdDetails,
  loadAdImage,
  setImageLoadingStatus,
} from "../../actions/ad";
// MUI Components
import { CardActionArea } from "@mui/material";
import CardContent from "@mui/material/CardContent";
import CardMedia from "@mui/material/CardMedia";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
// Files
import imagePlaceholder from "../../images/no-image-icon.png";
import { secondsToHmsShort } from "../../utils/secondToHms";

function MediaCard(props) {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleCardClick = (e) => {
    navigate(`/ads/${props.ad._id}`);
  };

  // Auction status based on the ad-details
  const updateAuctionStatus = (ad) => {
    if (ad.sold) {
      return "Sold";
    } else if (ad.auctionEnded) {
      return "Ended, not-sold";
    } else if (!ad.auctionStarted) {
      return "Upcoming";
    } else {
      return "Ongoing";
    }
  };

  return (
    <a
      onClick={(e) => {
        handleCardClick(e);
      }}
      style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}
    >
      <Card style={props.cardStyle}>
        <CardActionArea>
          {!props.dashCard && (
            <CardMedia
              component="img"
              height="180"
              src={props.ad.image ? props.ad.image : imagePlaceholder}
              alt="green iguana"
            />
          )}
          <CardContent>
            <Typography gutterBottom variant="h6" component="div">
              {props.ad.productName}
            </Typography>
            <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
              Price: $ {props.ad.currentPrice.$numberDecimal}
            </Typography>
            <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
              Remaining: {secondsToHmsShort(props.ad.timer)}
            </Typography>
            <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
              Status: {updateAuctionStatus(props.ad)}
            </Typography>
          </CardContent>
        </CardActionArea>
      </Card>
    </a>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  adDetails: state.ad.adDetails,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  loadAdDetails,
  loadAdImage,
  setImageLoadingStatus,
})(MediaCard);
```

I think the props loading is not getting catch by the render props. I face this issue with every props/adDetails in this page.

```js
return (
    <div className="ad__page">
      {props.loading ? (
        <LoadingDisplay />
      ) : (
        <>
          <Alert />
          {!props.adDetails.owner ? (
            <LoadingDisplay />
          ) : (
            <Box sx={boxStyle}>
              <Paper sx={paperStyle}>
                <Typography variant="h4">
                  {props.adDetails.productName}
                </Typography>

                <Box sx={adArea}>
                  <Box sx={imageContainer}>
                    {!props.imageLoading && (
                      <img
                        src={
                          props.adDetails.image
                            ? props.adImage
                            : imagePlaceholder
                        }
                        alt={props.adDetails.productName}
                        style={imageStyle}
                      />
                    )}
                  </Box>

                  <Box sx={descriptionArea}>
                    <Typography variant="h6">Description</Typography>
                    <Typography variant="body2">
                      {props.adDetails.description}
                    </Typography>
                    <Divider variant="middle" sx={{ margin: ".5rem" }} />

                    <Typography variant="h6">Info</Typography>
                    <Typography variant="body1">
                      Posted on: {getUTCDate(props.adDetails.createdAt)}
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography variant="body1">
                      Seller: {props.adDetails.owner.username}
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography variant="body1">
                      Base price: {props.adDetails.basePrice.$numberDecimal}
                    </Typography>
                    <Divider variant="middle" sx={{ margin: ".5rem" }} />

                    <Typography variant="h6">Auction</Typography>
                    <Typography variant="body1">
                      Status: {auctionStatus()}
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography variant="body1">
                      Bids: {props.adDetails.bids.length}
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography variant="body1">
                      Time remaining: {getTimeRemaining()}
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography variant="body1">
                      Current price: $
                      {props.adDetails.currentPrice.$numberDecimal}
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography variant="body1">
                      Current bidder:{" "}
                      {props.highestBid && props.highestBid.user.username}
                    </Typography>
                    <Divider variant="middle" sx={{ margin: ".5rem" }} />

                    {!ownerAd && (
                      <Box sx={bidContainer}>
                        <TextField
                          label="$"
                          id="bid-price"
                          size="small"
                          onChange={(e) => {
                            handleBidPriceChange(e);
                          }}
                        />
                        <Box sx={{ height: "auto" }}>
                          <Button
                            variant="contained"
                            disabled={bidButton}
                            onClick={(e) => handleSubmitBid(e)}
                            sx={bidButtonStyle}
                          >
                            Place bid
                          </Button>
                        </Box>
                      </Box>
                    )}
                    {ownerAd && (
                      <Box sx={bidContainer}>
                        <Box sx={{ height: "auto" }}>
                          <Button
                            variant="contained"
                            disabled={!startButton}
                            onClick={(e) => handleStartAuction(e)}
                            sx={bidButton}
                          >
                            Start Auction
                          </Button>
                        </Box>
                      </Box>
                    )}
                  </Box>
                </Box>
              </Paper>
            </Box>
          )}
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
```

I've double-checked my data fetching logic and the structure of props.item, and it seems to be correct. However, I'm still encountering this error. Can someone help me understand what might be causing this issue and how I can fix it?

Any assistance or insights into this problem would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It might be complaining about your bool check here: `src={props.ad.image ? props.ad.image : imagePlaceholder}`.
This reads: if `props.ad.image` is falsy, use the placeholder instead - checking for `image` on `props.ad` is good, but it won't catch if `props.ad` is itself undefined, which appears to be the case.

Try `src={props.ad ? (props.ad.image || imagePlaceholder) : imagePlaceholder}` - this will check that `props.ad` exists first and then return the placeholder if it doesn't, but also check for `image` if ad does exist and return the placeholder if *that* doesn't.